# train data using libsvm with best C and Gamma

Tags: visual-studio-2010, machine-learning, classification, libsvm

Hi I'm using libsvm (in VS2010) for training my data , I scaled the input and output data successfully using svm-scale.c and my data is ready to be trained ...

Now I have two problems:

1).

as I've read from LIBSVM documentation I realized that first I need to train my scaled data and obtain a model. then use this model for predicting the final result but the problem is when I want to train my system I don't know what is the best choose for my model parameters and specifically  (C,g) for training my data !!!.
what I do is that first I load my scaled data, then by using a svm_problem I fill svm_nodes with my train data then call this function :

> struct svm_model *svm_train(const struct svm_problem *prob,                    **const struct svm_parameter *param**);

2).
Also I'm not sure about the correct function calling of libsvm functions -> I mean I first use svm_train  and then svm_predict to see the result , and I don't know if I should call sth else or not ?!

> Model = svm_train(My_data,My_param); //I don't know how to fill my_param
>
> svm_node Test_Vector = svm_scale_data(x); //using the same algorithm as scaled_training data
>
> double result = svm_predict(Model,Test_Vector);

Thanks

Comment: I realized that using cross validation I can get the best c,gamma as grid.py do in python interface .... If somebody knows sth about this too I'd appreciated that ....

Answer (score 1):

If you want to call LIBSVM via C++, you can optimize parameters by letting LIBSVM do cross-validation internally. When doing so, you just need to loop over the parameter tuples (C, gamma) you want to test and let LIBSVM perform cross-validation instead of proper training.

You can get LIBSVM to perform cross-validation with the following API function:

```
void svm_cross_validation(const struct svm_problem *prob, const struct svm_parameter *param, int nr_fold, double *target);
```

To answer your other question: yes, it is perfectly fine to call `svm_train()` followed by `svm_predict()`.

Comment: sorry but can you please explain more about the meaning of internal optimization ? you mean I should call svm_train() and this function itself optimizes it's parameters internally ?!!! can you provide a pseudo code for a whole operation (from training and getting the best parameters to test the new samples and see the result ?)

Comment: Parameter optimization is always up to the user. You can use the provided cross-validation API function to test the efficacy of a given parameter tuple. You must implement a grid search method yourself (e.g. iterate over several values of C+gamma and test which one is best using `svm_cross_validation`).